# What is this alternative if/else syntax in PHP called?

Tags: php

What is the name of the following type of if/else syntax:

```
print $foo = ($hour < 12) ? "Good morning!" : "Good afternoon!";
```

I couldn't find any dedicated page in the php manual. I knew that it existed, because I've read a book (last year) with it, and now I found this [post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#91167).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called a ternary expression

http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php

You should note, this is not an "alternate syntax for if" as it should not be used to control the flow of a program.

In the simple example of setting variables, it can help you avoid lengthy if statements like this: (ref: [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary))

```
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}
```

**However** it can be used other places than just simple variable assignent

```
function say($a, $b) {
    echo "{$a} {$b}";
}

$foo = false;

say('hello', $foo ? 'world' : 'planet');

//=> hello planet
```

Answer (score 10):

It's called the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) - although many people call it the "`?:` operator" because "ternary" is such a seldom-used word.

Comment: Keep in mind that `?:` has a specific meaning, itself, as a shortcut for the longer syntax; `$dog = 'cat' ?: 'dog';` will result in $dog containing the string value: `cat`. It is identical to doing: `$dog = 'cat' ? 'cat' : 'dog';` or `if('cat') { $dog = 'cat'; } else { $dog = 'dog'; }` As such, I prefer just calling it the ternary operator. Or you could even call it the "short if" or "abbreviated if" syntax.